# Powershell stripping uncommon object properties

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have an Exchange script that's giving me information about the activation preference of our databases. The problem is that each database can have between 3 and 5 copies and when I run the following script, the "pref5" property is getting stripped out. I would normally rationalize this by saying that it's stripping uncommon object properties but that's not the case because some of the objects only have 3 copies - and therefore only 3 "pref" properties yet the databases with 4 copies show just fine. My output csv ends up with name, pref1, pref2, pref3, pref4 (why not pref5?). I have tested running this and capturing the array, and the pref5 property *is* there, it just does not make it down the pipeline when you group it with other objects that do not have a pref5.

```
$dbs = Get-MailboxDatabase "E2K10_DB*" | sort name

foreach ($db in $dbs) {
    $db | select -ExpandProperty ActivationPreference | foreach {
        $db | Add-Member -Type 'NoteProperty' -Name ("pref" + $_.value) -Value $_.key.tostring()
    }
}

$dbs | select name,pref? | Export-Csv $home\Desktop\DBPrefs.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You are conditionally adding the prefs properties. So the objects might not be matching up correctly since they should _all_ have the same properties. Populated or not. I have a suggestion I will put in an answer. Do they need to be in there own column?

Comment: I agree but the only thing I don't like is that there are objects with only pref1-3 and they export with a blank pref4, as expected. But the same is not true for pref5.

Comment: Yes, ideally I'd want the property to be blank if nonexistent (like pref4 is doing correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. This should be the start of what you are looking for. My CAS is running 2.0 PowerShell so I made sure the solution supported. It could be more terse if you have 3.0 or higher but it should still work either way.

```powershell
$dbs = Get-MailboxDatabase "E2K10_DB*" | Sort Name
$prefCount = $dbs | Select -ExpandProperty ActivationPreference | Measure-Object value -Maximum | Select -ExpandProperty Maximum
$results = $dbs | ForEach-Object{
    $props = @{}
    $name = $_.Name
    $props.Name = $name
    $dbActivationPreference = $_ | Select -ExpandProperty ActivationPreference
    For($prefIndex = 1;$prefIndex -le $prefCount;$prefIndex++){
        $indexValue = $dbActivationPreference | Where-Object{$_.Value -eq $prefIndex} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Key
        $props."pref$prefIndex" = $indexValue
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props
}

$propsOrder = @("Name") + (1..$prefCount | ForEach-Object{"pref$_"})
$results | Select $propsOrder | Export-Csv $home\Desktop\DBPrefs.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The issue I think you were having is that some of the DB's did not have the same set of `ActivationPreference`. So we need to figure out the maximum preferences so we know have many `pref#` we have to add.

`$prefCount` will get the number that is from a database with the highest preference count. Now we know how many values each entity will need.

`$props = @{}` is what we use to build the property list with all the prefs and name of the database.

We capture the `$results` and to ensure the order of the properties in the output we have to use `$propsOrder`

Comment: Yuck :)
Oh well - I had a feeling I'd have to do something like that. Thanks very much for putting this together!

Comment: It's not yuck. It's beautiful like a butterfly :)

Comment: BTW I figured out the reason it was stopping at 4 and not 3 - the first db in the query has four copies - so it was "setting the mold" for the rest of the objects in that array. That was driving me nuts!

Comment: That is what I was trying to tell you. Glad you could understand for yourself.

Comment: I mean it answered my question of why 4 instead of 3 since 3 was the highest common property.

Comment: That _was_ what I was trying to tell you. I'm just terrible at explaining things. Either way we fixed it. Perhaps I will run into you later!